# Integrate a stenciljs web component into a stenciljs app

Tags: npm, integration, node-modules, web-component, stenciljs

I did build some web components with stencil and published them on npm. Now I want to integrate them into another stencil app but I can't find any suggestions how to do so or the suggestions I found so far are not working.

e.g. there is no collections attribute anymore on the stencil config to include external components and this, which I found on the official documentation to distribute the components is not working:

In a stencil-app-starter app
Run npm install my-name --save
Add an import to the npm packages: import my-component;
Then you can use the element anywhere in your template, JSX, html etc.

I know that the components work because I successfully integrated them into an Angular and React App already.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Let us know your component names which you have already published to npm?

Comment: you can try it now with npm i amcis_stencil.
It now works fine. I rebuild everythning from scratch and the followed the official documentation again. I guess smething with a config was not correctly done by me...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just solved it. I'm building a StencilJS app and tried to use my component library [@elgervb/stencil-components](https://github.com/elgervb/stencil-components). 
Here is what I did to get it working:

I've added my library with:

```
yarn add @elgervb/stencil-components
```

and in `tsconfig.json` I added `typeRoots` to the `compilerOptions` to load my types:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@elgervb"
]
```

After that I can use all of my components in my app:

```
<evb-filepicker accept="image/*">
  <evb-button>Pick image</evb-button>
</evb-filepicker>
```

Hope this helps :-)